# What would be the British Equivalent Words to "Freshmen" "Sophomore"

Tags: british-english

I know that to describe which year you're in, with American English, people usually use words like:

- Freshmen - 1st year college/university student
- Sophomore - 2nd year
- Junior - 3rd year
- Senior - 4th year

However, since the British universities usually have three years in total, are there any equivalent words to these American expressions?

Or Does British people just say "I'm a third-year" instead of "I'm a junior"?

Comment: NB: Those terms also apply to high school — and occasionally also to other institutions as well.

Comment: @tchrist Thx I'm aware of that :-)

Comment: So, what would someone in Britain write instead of this: "If you’re coming upon your sophomore novel, this isn’t meant to discourage you. ... Here are a few tips for overcoming the sophomore slump:" [ http://kayepublicity.com/avoiding-the-sophomore-slump/ ]

Comment: @GEdgar - they'd use the word *'second'*. If you're thinking of "sophomore slump", the nearest equivalent would be ["Difficult Second Novel/Album"](http://www.theguardian.com/music/2003/sep/19/3)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you suggest, British English tends to just go by year number for University level students:

- Freshmen - *1st year student* or *1st year undergrad*
- Sophomore - *2nd year student* or *2nd year undergrad*

And so on until the final year (3rd year for Bachelor's Degree students and 4th year for Master's Degree students), the students of which are referred to as *final year students*.

Students who have completed their degree and are attempting to achieve a PhD typically do not use year numbering at all, and are merely referred to as *post-graduates*, which contrasts with students who complete their degree but do not go on to further education and are normally referred to as *graduates*.

British English never uses the terms *Freshman*, *Sophomore*, *Junior*, *Senior* etc (in any educational context). Use of those terms is not well understood in Britain, and most British English speakers would not understand what the term means.

Answer (score 10):

- *fresher* — first-year student within the first few weeks
- *first year*
- *second year*
- *third year* or *final year* — three-year courses
- *fourth year* or *final year* — four-year courses
- *finalists* — for those taking their final exams (or just last year)

Comment: I've never heard the term "finalists" used to refer to university students. It's normally used to refer to people who get to the last round in a competition.

Comment: @Matt That it is. I would not expect a student to describe themselves like this, but it is fairly common for teaching staff to refer to them this way.

Comment: I'm currently a final year student and while it's not used much at my university I've heard the term used a few times here and there. Having said that, I think the majority of people don't know the term