# How to express college student in each grade?

Tags: word-choice

It really bothers me:

> Should I say *I'm a college senior student*, or should I say *I'm a senior college student* (or *I'm a college senior student*)?
>
> Should I say *I'm a sophomore*, or should I say *I'm a sophomore college student*
> (or *I'm a college sophomore student*)? Ooh, English is tough!

Comment: Where are you located? The meaning of *college* varies from place to place, and the divisions of schooling vary from place to place.

Comment: @tchrist, "teenage text message" -I wonder if a term has been coined? The 'tchrist' ;-)

Comment: @choster China..

Comment: @tchrist Sorry,i did some researches and found written english is not simple.Much to learn.

Comment: @lee It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Are you asking about the word order— *senior college student* vs. *college senior student*? Are you asking about the [terms for each year](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110709)? Please edit your question to clarify. You may also be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @choster Both i think.

Comment: I think of *"sophomore"* as a noun, and not an adjective. So use *"I am a sophomore in college"* or *"I am a college student in my second year"*. None of *"sophomore student"*, *"sophomore college student"*, or *"college sophomore student"* sound correct to me (although it is quite clear what they all mean). The same is true for *freshman, junior, senior* when they have this meaning.

Comment: choster, that's a good point. Not only does the meaning of *college* vary in different parts of the world, but so does the terminology for it. The words in question are not used in England and the rest of the UK.

Comment: I would say "Hello, my name is tee". It is shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to word this is:

> I'm a senior in college.

This is because "college senior student," "senior college student," and "senior student" all sound wrong because senior in this sense is a noun and not an adjective. "Senior" as an adjective means "older" or "higher ranking," while "senior" as a noun refers to the last year of college or high school.

Comment: @RyeBread: if Jason added that *college senior student*, *senior college student*, and *senior student* all sound incorrect because *senior* in this sense is a noun and not an adjective, this would be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose between the above two, then the more befitting statement would be:

> I am a senior college student.

However, there are some possible alternatives to it:

Using the year in which you study - *I'm a 3rd year college student* or *I'm a 2nd year college student*, in case of first year we can also say *I'm a freshmen*.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: oh okie it just that '>' was bit hard to work with lel..

Comment: I’m afraid I would think a *senior college student* would be a superannuated one. :)  Best just to call them a *college freshman/sophomore/junior/senior*, to distinguish them from a high-school student of the corresponding year.

Answer (score 0):

**Magistrand**: [n. senior, fourth year university student](http://www.dictionarist.com/magistrand)

Comment: What about us 6th year seniors, Ultramagistrands?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

I am a senior student in my college.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> I'm a college senior.
>
> I'm a college sophomore.
>
> I'm a college freshman.

Comment: This is the clearest, cleanest, and (I should hope) the most oft-used solution.  It rings true to my native-speaker ear.

Comment: @tchrist In the same vein, can you say "I'm a junior high senior" in AmE?

Comment: No, you cannot, although that is a rather interesting turn of phrase.  Junior high doesn’t get special words for each year.  It is typically either a two-year stint for seventh- and eighth-graders, or sometimes a three-year one adding in sixth-graders. But saying a *junior high senior* begs for so many subclever misreadings that I am sure it has been used in jest more than once.